# Reconfigure Serilog Async Sink to remove EventLog for integration tests executed in CI/CD

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, serilog

**Problem**

I can't execute integration tests in CI/CD on Linux agent because of `Serilog.Sinks.EventLog` not supported on Linux.

**Description**

I have a fairly easy ASP.NET Core 7 application.

The application has the integration tests using `WebApplicationFactory` from Microsoft's `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Testing` NuGet.

The application uses Serilog for logging with Console & EventLog as sinks for the production environment, Console only for Development (*or I though so*) and it should **not** use EventLog if the application is under the test.

The production will use Windows Service deployment scenario. The logging into Windows EventLog is requested for this scenario to have some sort of logging.

The problems is that CI/CD execute these integration tests and it fails on `PlatformNotSupported` when Serilog configuration is constructed. We don't use Windows agents, but Linux.

I would like to keep it that way to avoid Windows specific features in code to support cheaper Linux agents.

**Problem definition**

How to inject a different configuration, ideally via `appsettings.{Something}.json`? Or how to prevent `LoggerConfigurationEventLogExtensions.EventLog(...)` fire the exception?

**What I have tried**

- `UseEnvironment("Testing")` doesn't work, probably because "Testing" is not standard environment.
- Inject specific JSON as config provider, but EventLog configuration is still initiated.
- Couple other approaches

One way or another, I would like keep the application source code changes to minimal because of that, ideally just code changes in the test project.

Any ideas?

**Factory setup**

```
protected override void ConfigureWebHost(IWebHostBuilder builder)
{
    var connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(_dbContainer.GetConnectionString())
    {
        InitialCatalog = "start-db",
    };
    _ = builder.ConfigureTestServices(services => services
        .AddDefaultTestAssets()
        .InjectTestConnectionStringProvider(connBuilder.ConnectionString)
        .InjectTestingDb(connBuilder.ConnectionString)
        .AddTestSecurity())
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration((c, b) =>
        {
            _ = b.AddJsonFile("appsettings.Testing.json"); // One attempt how to solve the problem.
            c.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName = "Testing";
        });
}
```

`Program.cs`:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder();

builder.AddServiceOptions();
builder.Host.UseSerilog();
builder.Configuration.AddEnvironmentVariables("SERVICE__");

builder.Services
    .AddCors()
    .AddRepositories()
    .AddInternalServices()
    .AddDefaultJsonSerializationCasePolicy()
    .AddCommonApiClient(builder.Configuration.GetRequiredSection("CommonApi"))
    .AddMediator(o =>
    {
        o.ServiceLifetime = ServiceLifetime.Transient;
        o.Namespace = "Service";
    })
    .AddTransient(typeof(IPipelineBehavior<,>), typeof(ValidationBehavior<,>))
    .AddTransient<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>()
    .AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())
    .AddValidatorsFromAssembly(Assembly.Load("Service.Common"))
    .AddEndpointsApiExplorer()
    .AddWindowsService()
    .AddSwaggerGen(o => o.SwaggerDoc(
        WebConsts.SwaggerDocName,
        new OpenApiInfo { Title = "API", Version = "1.0.0" }));

var app = builder.Build();

Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(app.Configuration).CreateLogger();

Log.Logger
    .ForContext("SourceContext", nameof(Program))
    .Information(
    "[{LogEvent:l}]The service starting",
    LogEvent.AppStarting);

app
    .MapApi()
    .RequireAuthorization(SecurityConstants.TokenAuthorizationPolicy);

app.UseCors(p => p
        .SetIsOriginAllowed(_ => true)
        .AllowCredentials())
    .UseMiddleware<ExceptionHandlingMiddleware>()
    .UseHttpLogging()
    .UseSerilogRequestLogging()
    .UseSwagger()
    .UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint(
        $"/swagger/{WebConsts.SwaggerDocName}/swagger.json",
        "Service.Api.V1"));

await app.AddEnvironmentSpecificAppConfiguration();

try
{
    await app.RunAsync();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Log.Logger.Critical(ex, "Application terminated unexpectedly");
}
finally
{
    Log.Logger.Information(
        "[{LogEvent:l}]The service is closing",
        LogEvent.AppClosing);
    Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

Production setup in `appsettings.json`:

```json
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console",
      "Serilog.Sinks.EventLog"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:u}][{Application}][{MachineName}][{ProcessName}:{ProcessId}][{ThreadId}][{SourceContext}][{Level:u3}]{Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            },
            {
              "Name": "EventLog",
              "Args": {
                "source": "{Application}",
                "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Error",
                "logName": "Application",
                "manageEventSource": true,
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:u}][{Application}][{MachineName}][{ProcessName}:{ProcessId}][{ThreadId}][{SourceContext}][{Level:u3}]{Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithThreadId",
      "WithProcessId",
      "WithProcessName"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "SEM.NG.SqlScriptExecutor"
    }
  },
```

What integration test should use (in theory - no EventLog):

```json
  "Serilog": {
    "Using": [
      "Serilog.Sinks.Console"
    ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Information",
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "Async",
        "Args": {
          "configure": [
            {
              "Name": "Console",
              "Args": {
                "outputTemplate": "[{Timestamp:u}][{Application}][{MachineName}][{ProcessName}:{ProcessId}][{ThreadId}][{SourceContext}][{Level:u3}]{Message}{NewLine}{Exception}"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    ],
    "Enrich": [
      "FromLogContext",
      "WithMachineName",
      "WithThreadId",
      "WithProcessId",
      "WithProcessName"
    ],
    "Properties": {
      "Application": "SEM.NG.SqlScriptExecutor"
    }
  },
```